# Argument VS variable declaration in IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I have always found IIFE horrible to read when it is passed several arguments. For example:

```
(function($, node, selector) {
  // ...
  return $(selector, node);
})(jQuery, document.body, "p > a");
```

Indeed, you first get the parameters, and it loose readability as you have to match them to the arguments of your IIFE.

But that something I often read. Why not just declaring variables in the IIFE, like below:

```
(function() {
  var $ = jQuery,
      node = document.body,
      selector = "p > a";
  // ...
  return $(selector, node);
})();
```

Having the key / value pair presented as above looks more readable. Why not doing so? (performance-related reasons? not mixing local and variables of the parent scopes?)

Florent

Comment: It's just a dependency injection. You separate the implementation from its dependencies.

Comment: back in the day, passing them sped up execution by avoiding extra clousure vs doing the lookup inside the function. it's also popular to privatize "$" when using more than one lib.

Comment: Thank you both for your explanations :).